# Do certain language features such as slicing, type erasure, copy elision, and return value optimization belong to a category under a specific name?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, behavior

This has been bothering me for quite some time now. I would want to find a complete list on what these "idioms" are called. I've tried searching "C++ Idioms", but that doesn't include RVO, or copy elision. RVO and copy elision are not necessarily language features; more like compiler optimizations. Would it be safe to call RVO and copy elision "compiler optimizations"? If so, trying to search Google for `c++ compiler optimizations` just brings me to a bunch of compiler flags.

I'm trying to find a name that these optimizations/behaviors fall under. I am not asking what these things do, I'm asking what they are.

Comment: Is slicing an optimization?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I wouldn't think it's an optimization. I would call it a language feature.

Comment: RVO and copy elision are not language features rather compiler support. Take a look at Bjarne Stroustrup in "C++ Programming language" it do not describe any of those, thy are even not present in book index.

Comment: Also slicing can fall into two categories, depending if it is intended or not, so I would say it can be feature or subtle bug.

Comment: How about "buzz words for commonly asked things on StackOverflow"? If your goal is classification, then it makes no sense. Those are different things. If you want to learn more of those things, just go to [C++] tag page, sort questions by upvotes and enjoy.